# Can I keep websql database open to improve performance?

Tags: html, transactions, persistence, web-sql

I have an HTML5 mobile app running on iOS and Android. Users will normally have a little bit of local data stored in a few tables. Let's say five tables with an average of three records.

Performance of websql is really bad. I read in [this post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130048/sqlite-performance---how-to-make-it-acceptable) that much of the delay is probably in opening and closing the database for each transaction. My users will normally only do one transaction at a time, so the time needed to open and close the database for each operation will usually be a relatively big chunk of total time needed.

I am wondering if I could just open the database once, dispense with all the transaction wrappers and just execute the sql straight away?

The table is never used by any other person or process than the user updating their data, or the app reading the data after an update and sending the data to a server for calculations and statistics.

Most crucially: if I follow the above strategy, and the database is never closed, but the user or the OS closes the app (properly speaking: the webview), will the changed data persist or be lost?

Comment: From experience, WebSQL performance is not that bad - inside a single transaction, inserting several thousand records takes less than a second. Five tables with three records should really be a piece of cake... Our JS client opens the db on startup and never closes it, and we have never lost any data after a transaction commit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem. I use the persistenceJS framework to deal with the local database. This keeps a copy of the websql data stored in a js object and keeps database and js object in sync. That's a process that takes a while, and I was putting everything in the "flush" handler, which comes after the sync.

Answer (score 0):

I also keep the connection open. For IndexedDB, I could keep open on UI and background thread at the same time without observing problem. I believe WebSQL will be the same. If you are using just JS file, you could try out my own [javascript library](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/starting/setup.html), it is very thin wrapper for both IndexedDB and WebSQL. But the library is written for IndexedDb style.